# Detecting if Snipping Tool is open within a web application

Tags: .net, vb.net, silverlight, flash

I was just wondering - is it possible to detect, with either .net, SilverLight, Flash or some other plugin, whether or not Snipping Tool is open, or detect when the user opens it (after the page has loaded)? Also is it possible to detect when print screen is pressed even if another window is active?

Comment: Not possible, anybody can call BitBlt().  It doesn't require a key press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not conclusively. It's possible to detect some uses based on keypress, but it's possible that they have a different window selected, print screen the whole desktop, and record that.